# Dump Array problems SQL Server

Tags: arrays, dump

I am using IPN Paypal script to automate my transactions, but I get the following error:

> Dump array error in my ipn log

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
$updateOrder = DB::Executa("UPDATE site_donations SET ultima_alteracao = '".time()."', transaction_code = '".$tid."', status = '".$finalStatus."', status_real = '".$status."' WHERE protocolo = '".$ref."' LIMIT 1");

if (!$updateOrder) {
    saveLog("Não foi possível atualizar o status da transação! #1", 1);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove LIMIT 1 at the end